# How do I update Intel e1000 driver? Server reverts to old driver on reboot

Tags: command-line, networking, drivers

I have a kvm server and I'm trying to update my Intel e1000 drivers. I can install the new drivers using the following code

```
make clean
make
make install
modprobe -rv e1000
modprobe e1000
```

Afterwards, when I run `ethtool -i eth0` it tells me that the driver is the new version (8.*)

But then when I reboot my server and run the same ethtool command it returns the old driver (7.*)

What's going on, and how do I stop it from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That module may be part of the initrd ramdisk. You should rebuild the initrd using the command

```
mkinitrd
```

Check the correct syntax 'cause now I'm not on linux.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the initrd has the old e1000e driver and it's getting loaded during initrd. Try rebuilding the initrd and it should pick up the newly-installed version.

Since you're on debian, the command: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` should do the trick.